# sqlite - works with file, dies with :memory:

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

My script fails tests when working with [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) base (via [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)) created in `:memory:` and passes tests when working with a base created with physical file.

The script is multi-threaded. I know it is not the best idea to use SQLite with multiple threads (locking, etc.), but I use SQLite to test script's DB interface only.

When I use `:memory:`, the script dies complaining that there is no table:

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError)
    no such table: content_info u'INSERT INTO content_info ...
```

The testing procedure (with [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) is as follows:

```
def setup_database():
    global global_engine
    # create database columns
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(...)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    global_engine = engine

@with_setup(setup_database)
def test_task_spoolers():
    check_database_content_from_another_thread()

def check_database_content_from_another_thread():
    global global_engine
    # from within other thread
    # create new session using global_engine
    # do some inserts
```

So in the setup I *do* create the database and the columns. I can see it also in logs (`echo=True`):

```
12:41:08 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE content_info (...

12:41:08 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
12:41:08 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO
    content_info (base_id, request_id, timestamp, ...
12:41:08 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (0, 0, 0, 'dummy_variant',
    None, 0)
12:41:08 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
OperationalError: (OperationalError)
    no such table: content_info u'INSERT INTO ...
```

My guess was that when I create the base in thread A, and then I use it in thread B, then B starts to operate on the base before it was actually created. But, I added `time.sleep(3)` after `create_all` and it didn't work.

And, as mentioned before, it works when I use a file instead of `:memory:`, even if the file is placed on virtual partition (so, in fact in memory). Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot create multiple connections to an in-memory database. Instead, a new connection to `:memory:` creates a *new* database.

From the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html):

> Every :memory: database is distinct from every other. So, opening two database connections each with the filename ":memory:" will create two independent in-memory databases.

This is different from an on-disk database, where creating multiple connections with the same connection string means you are connecting to one database.

You are creating a new connection for the thread, thus creating a *new* database that does not have the tables created.

Comment: Hm, I thought that if I use the same `engine` then I connect to the same base. Thanks!

Comment: @JakubM.: SQLAlchemy uses a connection pool, the engine acts as a connection factory, not the connection itself. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach to share the the connection between multiple threads:

```
from sqlalchemy.pool import StaticPool
engine = create_engine('sqlite://',
                connect_args {'check_same_thread':False},
                poolclass=StaticPool)
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#using-a-memory-database-in-multiple-threads